# awk: fatal: Unmatched ( or \( on gnuwin32 Gawk

Tags: awk, gawk

The following works when used w/ Mawk or Gawk on Linux, but I get an error when using gnuwin32 Gawk

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\bin\awk.exe -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "", $i) } 1' kpi-test.csv
awk: fatal: Unmatched ( or \(: /'' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(,, ",/
```

I know I could try cygwin, but I'd rather use gnuwin32 Gawk. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to execute it on Windows/DOS now. The quoting rules are different on that platform and the usual advice is to put your awk script in a file and use `awk -f script input` instead of trying to deal with the Windows quoting nightmare. I personally always use Cygwin on Windows and run awk from that.

Answer (score 0):

Any "one-liner" in a Windows command shell must be enclosed in double-quotes.  If the one-liner contains double-quotes, they must be prefaced with a backslash:

```
c:\> gawk "BEGIN { print(\"This will work.\") }"
This will work.

c:\>
```